# excel ^1.1.5 depedency conflict in Flutter?

Tags: excel, flutter, runtime-error

I have been trying to install excel: ^1.1.5 version. But all I am getting this error.

```
Because excel >=1.0.4 <2.0.0-null-safety depends on xml ^4.1.0 which depends on convert ^2.1.0, excel >=1.0.4 <2.0.0-null-safety requires convert ^2.1.0.
And because `json_serializable` >=4.0.3 depends on build ^2.0.0 which depends on convert ^3.0.0, excel >=1.0.4 <2.0.0-null-safety is incompatible with `json_serializable` >=4.0.3.
And because invoiceninja 0.0.9 depends on `json_serializable` ^4.1.0 and no versions of `invoiceninja` match >0.0.9 <0.1.0, excel >=1.0.4 <2.0.0-null-safety is incompatible with `invoiceninja` ^0.0.9.
So, because `etf` depends on both `invoiceninja` ^0.0.9 and excel ^1.1.5, version solving failed.
pub get failed (1; So, because `etf` depends on both `invoiceninja` ^0.0.9 and excel ^1.1.5, version solving failed.)
exit code 1
'''Version'''
 flutter doctor
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel dev, 2.11.0-0.1.pre, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18363.418], locale en-US)
```

Comment: Try using excel 2.0.0-null-safety-3

Comment: it didn't work either.